# IntelliJ Default Changelist not showing all the local changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I right-click on the project > Git > Compare with Branch, it shows all the local changes(10+ files), but in the Local Changes tab, the default changelist is only showing two files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Local changes" display uncommitted changes whereas "Compare with branch" shows the difference in committed files between branches (the current one and the selected one)